# pretty printing exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Is there any API that allows to prints all the exception-related info (stack trace, inner etc...)? Just like when the exception is thrown - all the data is printed to the standard output - is there any dedicated method that does it all?

thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928976/what-is-the-proper-way-to-display-the-full-innerexception

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());` not printing the exception

Comment: How pretty the result will be?!

Comment: It will be very  pretty!

Comment: Console.WriteLine() will auto _ToString()_ on it, and it is ugly still, very hard to see. Sometimes _ex.Message_ is good enough without blowing out too much details

Answer (score 7):

the `ToString` method of `Exception` does exactly that.

Comment: Are there any recommendations how to format things when overriding ToString, e.g. on e.g. a DisposersFailedException which may contain multiple exceptions if multiple exceptions were thrown in the course of disposing an object?

Answer (score 3):

Exception.ToString() ?

Answer (score 1):

For printing *exceptions* in **C#**, you can use **Debug.WriteLine()**:

```
    try
    {
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<<< catch : "+ ex.ToString());
    }
```

Also, you can use this for other exceptions, for example with **MySqlException**:

```
   try
    {
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<<< catch : "+ ex.ToString());            
    }
```

But, if you need printing a *Exception's Message*, you have to use **Message**:

```
    try
    {
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("<<< catch : "+ ex.Message);            
    }
```