# Finding the original exception

Tags: c#, exception, properties

I have an import routine that imports many values into properties of an Object. There are a lot of values to go into the Objects Properties and they can be in any order, so I use reflection to find a property then set its value.  This all works really well, except if there is an exception raised by the Objects properties setter method, I don't see it.

Code excerpt:

```
try
{
    PropertyInfo piInstance = MBtype.GetProperty(columnlist[intColumn]);
    piInstance.SetValue(newMailbox, CurrentRow[intColumn]);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    HelpFunc.writeToLog($"Error: '{ex.Message}'", "Error");
}
```

The property thowing the intial error code is:

```
throw new ArgumentException($"{value} must be valid email address", value);
```

However, when I look at the log it not telling me the argument exception, its telling me the error is:

"Error: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'"

i.e. the original exception is lost.The **setValue** is a Net function. How can I get the original exception, so I can grab the details for logging.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the inner Exception:

```
try
{
  PropertyInfo piInstance = MBtype.GetProperty(columnlist[intColumn]);
  piInstance.SetValue(newMailbox, CurrentRow[intColumn]);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   HelpFunc.writeToLog($"Error: '{ex.Message}', Inner Exception: '{ex.InnerException?.Message}'", "Error");
}
```

I recommend always log the `ToString()` method of the exception, because then you have all information (including stack trace an inner exceptions).

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/L1msAC

Comment: You could collect all InnerExceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9314368/284240
For example: `string.Join("; ", ex.GetInnerExceptions().Select(ex => ex.Message))`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is completely valid, however you can get way more thorough with it; which might be nice if you're trying to find where exactly an exception came from in a large code base, so StackTrace property can be a blessing. Here is what I use:

```cs
public void depositLog(Exception exception, string user, string path) 
{
    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        var st = new StackTrace(exception, true);

        var sourceFrame = Enumerable.Range(0, st.FrameCount).FirstOrDefault(i => st.GetFrame(i).GetFileLineNumber() > 0);
        w.WriteLine(version + user + "~~~~~  Encountered exception:   " + exception.ToString() + "STACKTRACE:  " + st.ToString() + sourceFrame.ToString());
    }
}
```

I've got this method assigneded like this in `Main()`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    lt.depositLog(eventArgs.Exception, "CATCHALLEXCEPTIONREPORTER for " + user, logPath);
};
```

So that every exception gets written into my log file, and I also use it in try/catch blocks where I want to add some more information to it.