# Catching Original Exception type

Tags: c#, exception

I would like to use a catch statement to catch an exception that was thrown by code below the current level.

I am using this code to catch the exception

```
catch (ArgumentException ex)
  {
    HelpFunc.writeToLog($"ArgumentException: '{ex.InnerException?.Message}'", "Error");
  }
catch (Exception ex)
  {
    HelpFunc.writeToLog($"Exception: '{ex.InnerException?.Message}'", "Error");
  }
```

See this for why I'm using InnerException [Finding the original exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77373548/finding-the-original-exception)

This works great but the exception gets picked up as a general exception, not the original ArgumentException type. Is there a way of catching by the original thrown exception?

Answer (score 1):

AH,  I've found this method

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex.InnerException is ArgumentException)
    {
    HelpFunc.writeToLog($"Inner Exception: Argument Exception: '{ex.InnerException?.Message}'", "Error");
    }
```

and this seems to pick it up.