# Get All Exception messages, including InnerException in C#

Tags: c#, exception, inner-exception

How can I easily get all Exception messages, including the InnerExceptions in C#, to output to console or logging for example?

Comment: Show what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck.

Comment: *...to output to console **for logging** for example?* Depending on the logging framework they just accept an exception and they will recursively log its inner exceptions. A bit too broad and basic question imho.

Comment: The idea of the question was to do some knowledge sharing, because I couldn't find a concise answer when I was looking for it, so hopefully the question should make it easier for people to find a good solution in the future.

Comment: That already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928976/what-is-the-proper-way-to-display-the-full-innerexception/5928991#5928991. No need to re-invent that wheel. Could anyone close that as a duplicate please?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to write a recursive function:

For Example:

```
    public static string ExceptionMessages(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException == null)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }

        return ex.Message + "  " + ExceptionMessages(ex.InnerException);

    }
```

This will output all the Messages in a single string.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you'd just loop:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    while (ex != null)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sinatr there's a trade off between detail vs context; when there are lots of inner exceptions (XmlSerializer is a beast for this!), ToString() is simply too voluminous, where-as looking through just the `.Message` output will very quickly tell you the problem. It depends on the context, is what I'm saying. Yes, sometimes `ex.ToString()` will be just fne